# Non-greedy decision tree / random forest implementation(s) in Python

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees

The standard [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) is trained using a greedy approach for computational feasibility. However, there are a number of alternative methods such as "[lookahead](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14572)" or using [bilevel optimization](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-021-00506-x). Such approaches seem to be useful especially in the case of noisy data.

I wonder if there are "off the shelf" Python implementations (e.g. `pip` packages) of non-greedy ways to grow decision trees/random forests. Can anyone recommend some Python implementations.

Or alternatively, are there some known Python implementations e.g. on Github etc.?

Comment: The only one I've seen in R is using evolutionary algorithms. It didn't work very well.

Comment: Cheers, do you remember the name of the package?

Comment: This one https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evtree/vignettes/evtree.pdf.